# Growing healthy, bushy, dark green redwoods

Tags: tree-care

I’ve recently planted some redwoods (coastal redwoods).  I’ve noticed that some redwoods in my area (Sacramento) are gorgeous, dense (thick with branches), and are dark green.  Others in this area are skinny, straggley, and lighter green.  I very much want my redwoods to be the former.  But how do I make that happen??

Comment: pictures please

Comment: I think you see different redwoods. The denser trees are the coastal redwoods, but it seems to me that are green/blue, not really dark green. In late winter/springs the mountain redwoods get temporarily leaves green yellowish.